# Why am I not logged in?

Tags: php, facebook

I am logged into facebook on my phone and my laptop.  However, when I run the following scripts on these devices,

config.php

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'myAppId',
'secret' => 'myAppSecret',
'cookie' => true,
));
?>
```

and index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
/* Get a valid session */
$session = $facebook->getUser();
$me = null;
if($session) {
/* Check if session is valid */
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
}
if ($me) {
echo 'User is logged in and has a valid session';
}
else {
echo 'Session expired or user has not logged in yet. 
Redirecting...';
echo '<script> top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl()
.'";</script>';
}
?>
```

I get

Session expired or user has not logged in yet. 
          Redirecting...

However, after I logged in at this site (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/) via facebook at my laptop, I now get

User is logged in and has a valid session.

Why is that?

Comment: Not sure you want your `appid` and `secret` out there for everyone to see...

Comment: If the appId and secret aren't dummies you should definetively edit that out.

Comment: Too late, permanently captured them.

Comment: App Id is a public item and doesn't matter...however secret key is something you should hold under lock-n-key.  I'd suggest going to your app and generating a new secret key before bad people have their way with your app.

Comment: @DMCS I don't code on Facebook, so I didn't know for sure. But I figured at the very least, having both up there is worse than just one or the other.

Comment: dont use the facebook api, its BS.

Comment: @Shiplu - Are you SERIOUS? Is that real?

Comment: @JaredFarrish OMG. It seems just a tag. :o

Comment: @Shiplu - I'm just thinking, wow. Has SO jumped the shark? It doesn't appear to be a totally new SE site, just SO with a FB filter by default.

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know what facebook.stackoverflow.com does, but it makes sense that you script cannot use cookies of another application/browser. A cookie is just a little piece of local data, but each browser stores it in a different way and in a different place. Logging in in a browser doesn't mean your script can use those same stored credentials.

Comment: How can I use script(PHP) to access my Facebook session as is? I am logged into Facebook via IE on my laptop, and via Android native browser on my phone.